# CSS grid gets distorted with width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a CSS grid, but it gets scattered when using width.

I want 3 posts on a row. I believe the problem might be with my border box. Only the desktop view is affected, mobile view looks perfectly normal.

I am using `width: 33.333%` to achieve the grid.

What is wrong with the CSS code?

```css
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/


/*                           1. Common Style                             */


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font: 400 14px / 1.8 "Whitney SSm A", "Whitney SSm B", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 2000px) {
  a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .list-item-header {
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 0 4px;
    color: #555A72;
  }
  .list-item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 33.333%;
  }
  .list-item-body {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    color: rgba(85, 90, 114, 0.9);
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .list-item-link {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: blue;
  }
  .greed {
    display: block;
    padding: 60px;
  }
  li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    padding: 30px;
  }
  .cont {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: auto;
  }
  .contt {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 1064px;
  }
  l::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 35px;
    right: 0;
    border-top: solid 1px rgba(35, 31, 32, 0.25);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .list-item-header {
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 0 4px;
    color: #555A72;
  }
  .list-item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 33.333%;
  }
  .list-item-body {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    color: rgba(85, 90, 114, 0.9);
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .list-item-link {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: blue;
  }
  .greed {
    display: block;
    padding: 60px;
  }
  li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .cont {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: auto;
  }
  .contt {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 1064px;
  }
  l::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 35px;
    right: 0;
    border-top: solid 1px rgba(35, 31, 32, 0.25);
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<head>

  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/png">
  <title>Blog posts</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/blog.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cont contt">
    <ul class="greed">
      <li>
        <a href="/blog/django-database-relationship">
          <h3 class="list-item-header">Django database relationship</h3>
          <p class="list-item-body">
            ForeignKey is only one-to-one if you specify ForeignKey(Dude, unique=True), so with the above code you will get a Dude with multiple PhoneNumbers. <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cont contt">
    <ul class="greed">
      <li>
        <a href="/blog/database-models-for-tables-reservation-and-customer">
          <h3 class="list-item-header">Database Models for tables, reservation and customer</h3>
          <p class="list-item-body">
            Class Customer(models.Model): email = models.EmailField() # And whatever other custom fields here; maybe make a ForeignKey link to User? <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cont contt">
    <ul class="greed">
      <li>
        <a href="/blog/python-package-basics">
          <h3 class="list-item-header">Python package basics</h3>
          <p class="list-item-body">
            https://dzone.com/articles/executable-package-pip-install <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cont contt">
    <ul class="greed">
      <li>
        <a href="/blog/flask-sitemap">
          <h3 class="list-item-header">Flask sitemap</h3>
          <p class="list-item-body">
            Sitemap route @app . route ( '/sitemap.xml' , methods =[ 'GET' ]) def sitemap (): try : """Generate sitemap.xml. <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cont contt">
    <ul class="greed">
      <li>
        <a href="/blog/git-commands">
          <h3 class="list-item-header">Git commands</h3>
          <p class="list-item-body">
            The following are git commands thm <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cont contt">
    <ul class="greed">
      <li>
        <a href="/blog/creating-a-cicd-pipeline-with-jenkins-and-also-eks-clusters-through-aws-cloudformation-and-deploys-a">
          <h3 class="list-item-header">Creating a CI/CD Pipeline with Jenkins and also EKS Clusters through AWS CloudFormation and deploys a Nginx image</h3>
          <p class="list-item-body">
            GitHub repo notes. Creating a CI/CD Pipeline with Jenkins and also EKS Clusters through AWS CloudFormation and deploys a Nginx image. <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cont contt">
    <ul class="greed">
      <li>
        <a href="/blog/navigation-menu-css-from-codepen">
          <h3 class="list-item-header">Navigation menu CSS from codepen</h3>
          <p class="list-item-body">
            Navigation menu https://codepen.io/kirstenhumphreys/pen/vgaKmG Nav Bar https://codepen.io/MilanMilosev/pen/GJbGJq <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cont contt">
    <ul class="greed">
      <li>
        <a href="/blog/creating-virtual-environments-for-python">
          <h3 class="list-item-header">Creating virtual environments for python</h3>
          <p class="list-item-body">
            Steps in creating a virtual environment for a python project <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cont contt">
    <ul class="greed">
      <li>
        <a href="/blog/push-empty-git-to-check-ci">
          <h3 class="list-item-header">Push empty git to check ci</h3>
          <p class="list-item-body">
             Sometimes, you need to push a commit to Git purely to check if some CI thing is working. The allow-empty flag lets you push a <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cont contt">
    <ul class="greed">
      <li>
        <a href="/blog/webscraping-with-python-for-data-collection">
          <h3 class="list-item-header">Webscraping with Python for data collection</h3>
          <p class="list-item-body">
            What is webscraping <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>







</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should use `display: grid` for this layout.

Answer (score 2):

You are better off using `flex-box` or `grid` for this. There are a few things with your code that needed to be changed:

1. You have `float` and `width` set on your inner `li` item. That doesn't work when it's a child element, so, the `li` was floating in relation to its parent `ul`.
2. You can move the padding on the `ul.greed` to the `.cont` element instead.
3. I wrapped all your code in a `wrapper` element that has `display: flex` so the `.cont` elements become flex children.
4. I adjusted the media query to make it a bit more readable.
5. You could simplify your HTML a ton as well, but I left it since it may be auto-generated.

```css
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/


/*                           1. Common Style                             */


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font: 400 14px / 1.8 "Whitney SSm A", "Whitney SSm B", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cont {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.list-item-header {
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 0 4px;
  color: #555A72;
}

.list-item-body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  color: rgba(85, 90, 114, 0.9);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.list-item-link {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: blue;
}

.greed {
  display: block;
}

li {
  padding: 30px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

li::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 35px;
  right: 0;
  border-top: solid 1px rgba(35, 31, 32, 0.25);
}

@media (min-width: 801px) {
  .cont {
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<head>

  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/png">
  <title>Blog posts</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/blog.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cont contt">
      <ul class="greed">
        <li>
          <a href="/blog/django-database-relationship">
            <h3 class="list-item-header">Django database relationship</h3>
            <p class="list-item-body">
              ForeignKey is only one-to-one if you specify ForeignKey(Dude, unique=True), so with the above code you will get a Dude with multiple PhoneNumbers. <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
            </p>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="cont contt">
      <ul class="greed">
        <li>
          <a href="/blog/database-models-for-tables-reservation-and-customer">
            <h3 class="list-item-header">Database Models for tables, reservation and customer</h3>
            <p class="list-item-body">
              Class Customer(models.Model): email = models.EmailField() # And whatever other custom fields here; maybe make a ForeignKey link to User? <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
            </p>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="cont contt">
      <ul class="greed">
        <li>
          <a href="/blog/python-package-basics">
            <h3 class="list-item-header">Python package basics</h3>
            <p class="list-item-body">
              https://dzone.com/articles/executable-package-pip-install <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
            </p>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="cont contt">
      <ul class="greed">
        <li>
          <a href="/blog/flask-sitemap">
            <h3 class="list-item-header">Flask sitemap</h3>
            <p class="list-item-body">
              Sitemap route @app . route ( '/sitemap.xml' , methods =[ 'GET' ]) def sitemap (): try : """Generate sitemap.xml. <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
            </p>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="cont contt">
      <ul class="greed">
        <li>
          <a href="/blog/git-commands">
            <h3 class="list-item-header">Git commands</h3>
            <p class="list-item-body">
              The following are git commands thm <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
            </p>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="cont contt">
      <ul class="greed">
        <li>
          <a href="/blog/creating-a-cicd-pipeline-with-jenkins-and-also-eks-clusters-through-aws-cloudformation-and-deploys-a">
            <h3 class="list-item-header">Creating a CI/CD Pipeline with Jenkins and also EKS Clusters through AWS CloudFormation and deploys a Nginx image</h3>
            <p class="list-item-body">
              GitHub repo notes. Creating a CI/CD Pipeline with Jenkins and also EKS Clusters through AWS CloudFormation and deploys a Nginx image. <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
            </p>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="cont contt">
      <ul class="greed">
        <li>
          <a href="/blog/navigation-menu-css-from-codepen">
            <h3 class="list-item-header">Navigation menu CSS from codepen</h3>
            <p class="list-item-body">
              Navigation menu https://codepen.io/kirstenhumphreys/pen/vgaKmG Nav Bar https://codepen.io/MilanMilosev/pen/GJbGJq <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
            </p>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="cont contt">
      <ul class="greed">
        <li>
          <a href="/blog/creating-virtual-environments-for-python">
            <h3 class="list-item-header">Creating virtual environments for python</h3>
            <p class="list-item-body">
              Steps in creating a virtual environment for a python project <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
            </p>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="cont contt">
      <ul class="greed">
        <li>
          <a href="/blog/push-empty-git-to-check-ci">
            <h3 class="list-item-header">Push empty git to check ci</h3>
            <p class="list-item-body">
               Sometimes, you need to push a commit to Git purely to check if some CI thing is working. The allow-empty flag lets you push a <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
            </p>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="cont contt">
      <ul class="greed">
        <li>
          <a href="/blog/webscraping-with-python-for-data-collection">
            <h3 class="list-item-header">Webscraping with Python for data collection</h3>
            <p class="list-item-body">
              What is webscraping <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
            </p>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>






</body>

</html>
```

### Simplified HTML

```css
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/


/*                           1. Common Style                             */


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font: 400 14px / 1.8 "Whitney SSm A", "Whitney SSm B", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cont {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.list-item-header {
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 0 4px;
  color: #555A72;
}

.list-item-body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  color: rgba(85, 90, 114, 0.9);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.list-item-link {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: blue;
}

.cont::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 35px;
  right: 0;
  border-top: solid 1px rgba(35, 31, 32, 0.25);
}

@media (min-width: 801px) {
  .cont {
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<head>

  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/png">
  <title>Blog posts</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/blog.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cont contt">
      <a href="/blog/django-database-relationship">
        <h3 class="list-item-header">Django database relationship</h3>
        <p class="list-item-body">
          ForeignKey is only one-to-one if you specify ForeignKey(Dude, unique=True), so with the above code you will get a Dude with multiple PhoneNumbers. <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="cont contt">
      <a href="/blog/django-database-relationship">
        <h3 class="list-item-header">Django database relationship</h3>
        <p class="list-item-body">
          ForeignKey is only one-to-one if you specify ForeignKey(Dude, unique=True), so with the above code you will get a Dude with multiple PhoneNumbers. <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="cont contt">
      <a href="/blog/django-database-relationship">
        <h3 class="list-item-header">Django database relationship</h3>
        <p class="list-item-body">
          ForeignKey is only one-to-one if you specify ForeignKey(Dude, unique=True), so with the above code you will get a Dude with multiple PhoneNumbers. <span class="list-item-link">
                            Read the post.
                        </span>
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why using that HTML strucure, it looks unnecessarily complicated!
Your problem is that the divs(.cont.contt) have a height and interacts with each other misaliging everything else, I don't think is a correct approach.

A partial solution might be to forse a height to 0 but is not clean at all.

I'd suggest to revist the strucure, maybe without using lists where not necessary or going directly with the [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid).

If I missed something let me know!

Have a nice day

Comment: i added height to the list styles along with the height 0. it worked.